# jQuery UI replacement for "distance" and "delay" options

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

According to [the jQuery UI API Documentation](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12), the "Distance" and "Delay" options are deprecated as of version 1.12. Specifically:

> (#10615) Interactions should be instantaneous. These settings are typically used to prevent accidental drags, but a proper fix for that is to improve the user experience, e.g., using handles to avoid accidental drags.

I am using jQuery UI to develop an RPG map builder. Users can drag tiles from the selection area to the grid to place them, or they can click a tile to set it as the "active" tile, then click on tiles in the grid to convert them to a copy of the "active" tile. The issue I run into is that a click-and-*very slight* drag on a set tile will cause the tile to be removed. I feel using a handle to drag tiles that are already on the map would detract from the user experience by causing them to have to set their pointer to an even smaller area than the tile.

So my question is: What can I use in place of these functions? Would it be best to stay on an old version of jQuery UI? Would it be better to write code to mimic this functionality? *Should* I use a handle for items already on the grid?

I think I can do a check for if (the dragged element (ui.draggable) is the same as the drop target (event.target), but I'm having trouble coming up with the logic.

My code is located at https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/OzvbdV. The relevant functions are setDraggableTiles() and setDroppableTiles(), below:

```
function setDroppableTiles() {
    $("#grid .tile").droppable({
        accept: ".tile",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            drop(event,ui);
        }
    });
}

function setDraggableTiles() {
    $(".tile").not("#grid .placeholder").draggable({
        revert: false,
        helper: "clone",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var $ele = $(event.target);
            console.log($ele);
            console.log($(ui.draggable));
            if ($ele.hasClass("tile-set")) {
                $ele
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass("placeholder tile");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#grid .tile").not(".placeholder").addClass("tile-set");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would make use of `start` and `stop` to calculate distance. You can get the position of the element in each and then calculate the distance from start to stop. Not sure what you were using delay for; so I can't really speak to that.

Comment: I would move the `delay` portion to `revert` This way if an item is clicked and moved, by accident, it can revert; it can also become `active`. If it is truely dragged and dropped, then it would not revert.